# Twitter OAuth - works with cURL but not PHP stream

Tags: php, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth

I am trying to retrive an OAuth bearer token from Twitter using `file_get_contents` (can't use cURL as i'm hosting on GAE)

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'https' => array(
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'header'  => 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxkfPTi8NrdAlK0xxxxx", oauth_callback="http://dev.mysite.com/auth/oauth/twitter", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1391622508", oauth_nonce="xxxxxaDoawlKjDODdxczL2JIow0AF1JkGa4fxxxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="xxxxznCGJWmBheTa/cCSEINxxxxx"',
          'timeout' => 5,
        ),
      ));
$response = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', false, $context);
```

But no matter what I seem to do I always get a 401. Maybe I can't see the wood for the trees now but I can't see whats wrong here. The parameters I am passing work fine if I use a cURL based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your headers need to be separated by \n not commas.

e.g.

```
'header' => 'Header1: foo\nHeader2: bar',
```

etc

Comment: no that didn't help, but thanks. in other news i read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) that it should be `'http' => array(` even though this is an ssl connection

Comment: Actually you need to use \r\n to separate headers, not just \n.